# Adding loop to captured macro in HostExplorer mainframe terminal emulator

Tags: loops, automation

I'm working with the HostExplorer mainframe terminal emulator.
I am not a programmer. I'm just looking for some boring work automation.
I captured a simple macro that mimics the way I input data into terminal.
After opening it in text editor it looks like this:

```
Dim HostExplorer as Object
Dim MyHost as Object
Dim Rc as Integer

Dim iPSUpdateTimeout

On Error goto GenericErrorHandler

Set HostExplorer = CreateObject("HostExplorer") ' Initialize HostExplorer Object
Set MyHost = HostExplorer.HostFromProfile("$PROGRAMFILES$\WERS\WAJ1.hep") ' Set object for the desired session
If MyHost is Nothing Then Goto NoSession

iPSUpdateTimeout = 60       ' WaitPSUpdated timeout set to 60 seconds

MyHost.RunCmd("Newline")
MyHost.RunCmd("Newline")
Rc = MyHost.Keys("NS")    
If Rc <> 0 Then Goto OnKeyboardError
MyHost.RunCmd("Pf2")
Rc = MyHost.WaitPSUpdated( iPSUpdateTimeout, TRUE )
If Rc <> 0 Then Goto OnWaitPSUpdatedTimeout
Exit Sub
```

My work is to put a code in a certain screen and then execute the macro.
Can this be turned into a loop where next code from the list is being pasted into the field and executing the macro? The list can be in Excel or incorporated into the macro code.

Thank you